# socket programming gethostbyname() returns null (maybe cause of host deletion)

Tags: c, sockets

I'm checking an open source code of a messenger which is not supported anymore.(gtmess .97)(it uses sys/socket.h for it's socket programming).

Unfortunately encountered gethostbyname() function and it returns null for the address which is given as hostname(messenger.hotmail.com), i tried to change code using getaddrinfo() but even getaddrinfo() says there isn't such server.

the question is, is there a way to fix it?(also please consider I'm beginner in socket programming)

here is the code:(commented part is what was written in the source code and uncommented part is mine part which tried to simulate using another method):

```
/* connect a client socket to a server and return a socket descriptor */
int ConnectToServer(char *addr, int defport)
{  
    /*
    int sfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    struct hostent *host;
    char hostname[256];
    int port;
    int err;

    ParseAddr(hostname, &port, defport, addr);


    if ((sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        return -1;

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    host = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if (host == NULL) {
        err = errno;
        close(sfd);
        errno = err;
        return -2;
    }

    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr =  *((int *) host->h_addr_list[0]);

    if (connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) {
        err = errno;
        close(sfd);
        errno =err;
        return -3;
    }

    return sfd;
    */




    struct addrinfo hints, *res , *p;
    int sockfd;
    int err;

    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;

    getaddrinfo("messenger.hotmail.com","1863",&hints,&res);

    if((sockfd=socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol))<0)
        return -1;

    if(connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen)){
        err = errno;
        close(sockfd);
        errno =err;
        return -3;
    }

    return sockfd;
}
```

edit:
I changed server and loop over to connect but it seems new server has problem too which give connection reset by peer in send() part

```
/* connect a client socket to a server and return a socket descriptor */
int ConnectToServer(char *addr, int defport)
{   
    struct addrinfo hints, *res , *p;
    int sockfd;
    int err;
    int rv;

    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;

    if(rv=getaddrinfo("messenger.hotmail.geo.msnmessenger.msn.com.akadns.net","1863",&hints,&res)!=0){
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return 1;
    };
    for(p=res;p!=NULL;p=p->ai_next){
        if((sockfd=socket(p->ai_family,p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol))<0){
            continue;
        }

        if(connect(sockfd,p->ai_addr,p->ai_addrlen)){
            err = errno;
            close(sockfd);
            errno =err;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    if(p==NULL)
        return -3;

    return sockfd;

}
```

Comment: Getaddrinfo may return more than one result, you should scan each of them and try to create a socket and then connect.  Of course, if things are as in dbush's answer ...

Comment: yea but getaddrinfo even don't work to loop over it.

Comment: you guys were right, changing server to messenger.hotmail.geo.msnmessenger.msn.com.akadns.net and loop over solve the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname messenger.hotmail.com is no longer valid.

It does have a CNAME record for messenger.hotmail.geo.msnmessenger.msn.com.akadns.net, however there is no IP address associated with it.  So you won't get any valid addresses back.

Comment: at first it was letting me to connect but now get connection refused in connect() function, anyway by the part there is no IP address associated with it you mean may I get error in other parts? cause it was giving signal error.

Comment: @Me. If `getaddrinfo` returns an error (which you aren't currently checking for) you can't expect do anything useful with the result object.  The rest of the program is undefined from that point on.

Comment: you mean i have to loop over linked list after getaddrinfo() and delete those return? cause i think if getarrinfo() returns error program will terminate automatically. @dbush